# NHibernate, subquery to select max value, right query is formed, but doesnt get executed

Tags: nhibernate

```
IList lFolioHistory;
ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();

var detq = NHibernate.Criterion.DetachedCriteria.For<FolioHistory>("e2");
detq.SetProjection(Projections.Alias(Projections.Max("Foliohistdate"), "maxFoliohistdate"));

detq.Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("e2.Memberid", "e.Memberid"));

ICriteria sc = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(FolioHistory), "e");
sc.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Eq("e.Memberid", iMemberId));
sc.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Subqueries.PropertyEq("Foliohistdate", detq));
lFolioHistory = sc.List();
```

right query is formed as below, but doesn't get executed.

> SELECT this_.foliohist_id as foliohist1_27_0_, this_.member_id as member2_27_0_, this_.foliohist_txnamt as foliohist3_27_0_, this_.foliohist_date as foliohist4_27_0_, this_.foliohist_balance as foliohist5_27_0_, this_.foliohist_remarks as foliohist6_27_0_, this_.foliohist_crby as foliohist7_27_0_ FROM hbms_foliohistory this_ WHERE this_.member_id = ?p0 and this_.foliohist_date = (SELECT max(this_0_.foliohist_date) as y0_ FROM hbms_foliohistory this_0_ WHERE this_0_.member_id = this_.member_id)

Comment: What do you mean doesn't get executed? you don't see a result? you get an error? have you looked at using NHibernate Profiler to see what's getting sent?

Answer (score 0):

Query wasn't getting executed, and was throwing and error. Finally figured out it to be a date error. Resolved it. Sorry for bothering you all.